# Experience with AppFigures.com?

Tags: iphone, macos

I was considering using AppFigures.com to track my app sales/rankings/reviews. I'm a little wary of giving them my developer account credentials. Does anyone have any experience with this website? Is it safe?

Comment: I've used them off and on with the free account for over a year, I find they are one of the best out there for aggregating your sales info. The auto updating system and emails are great, all your numbers delivered to your inbox without having to go look for them.

Comment: @Sam please provide some code for appFigures API.
i am using this code: https://github.com/kylehickinson/AppFiguresAPI
but, it's not working

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We've tracked our sales with them for over a year without any problem. For AppFigures or any other app you wish to use to retrieve your financials you should not use your developer credentials, but a financial user. You can create one on ItunesConnect under Manage Users, select the financial role, this will give that user access only to the information it needs.

Comment: Awesome, great idea - thanks- they really should recommend that when you sign up !